# Finding differences and similarities between python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to find the differences, additions and changes of 2 arrays.

If I have 2 arrays that look like this:

```
array1 = [{'id': 1001, 'details': [{'fname': 'James', 'lname': 'Bond'}, {'fname': 'Bea', 'lname': 'rose'}]},{'id': 1002, 'details': [{'fname': 'Paul', 'lname': 'Reo'}}]

array1 = [{'id': 1001, 'details': [{'fname': 'James', 'lname': 'Bond'}, {'fname': 'Frank', 'lname': 'Livio'}]},{'id': 1002, 'details': [{'fname': 'Paul', 'lname': 'Reo'}, {'fname': 'Rose', 'lname': 'Clapp'}]}, {'id': 1003, 'details': [{'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Lennon'}]}]
```

How can I find the similarities and the differences?

I have tried a couple of things using for loops and if statements but nothing seems to work.

For example, I would like the output to be:

1002 - `{'fname': 'Rose', 'lname': 'Clapp'}` // As is it missing from array1

1001 - `{'fname': 'Frank', 'lname': 'Livio'}` // As it is different from array1

1003 - `{'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Lennon'}` // As it has been added to array2 and missing from array1

I can't seem to find a way to to this in python with text in the array's

Comment: Check out numpy setdiff function https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse through the list and use the in operator to see if the item does not exist the same way in the other list. Use a set to avoid duplicates.

```
differences = set()
for item in array2:
    if item not in array1:
        differences.add(str(item))
for item in differences:
    print(item)
```

Gives me the following output:

```
{'id': 1003, 'details': [{'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Lennon'}]}
{'id': 1002, 'details': [{'fname': 'Paul', 'lname': 'Reo'}, {'fname': 'Rose', 'lname': 'Clapp'}]}
{'id': 1001, 'details': [{'fname': 'James', 'lname': 'Bond'}, {'fname': 'Frank', 'lname': 'Livio'}]}
```